# Possible Basement Window Well Leak?

Tags: basement, leak

this evening I went into my basement to work out and noticed a leak on the basement floor. Based on the pics included, it looks like the water is coming through the window well. What’s kind of puzzling is that this has never happened before. The gap, outside, between the ground and the window well is 6-8 inches. It did rain today but not enough to fill the window well. Any ideas what’s going on here?

[image: img1]

[image: img2]

[image: img3]

[image: img4]

Comment: It could be the water in the window well drains too slowly. Try rod the stormwater line, which can cause water in the well to back up.

Comment: It could also be blowing rain hitting against the window which may not be well sealed on the outside and leaking through around the frame.  Pictures of the window on the outside would help.